# Bamboo fails with JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE in Maven task on CentOS 7

Tags: java, maven, bamboo, java-home

I am running Bamboo on CentOS 7. My `JAVA_HOME/bin/java` and `java` commands refer to the same thing, and they are set properly:

```
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre
~$
```

I am also setting my `JAVA_HOME` variable in `.bash_profile`. I have put it in `<bamboo installation dir>/bin/setenv.sh` too. However, in my Maven tasks in Bamboo fail with:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I don't know how to debug this and how can I provide any further information. When I ssh into the server that Bamboo is installed, I can run `mvn` commands without any issues.

Comment: "Don't argue with the tool" :-p - your JAVA_HOME is indeed set to a JRE (see the trailing `/jre` in the path you set.  Remove that trailing bit, and then you will have set it to a JDK - and Maven tasks will work.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have been running Bamboo for about 2 years now with the same `JAVA_HOME`. Until recently we migrated to a new server, and then this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is not about how you set the `JAVA_HOME` variable for Bamboo, but it's about how Bamboo sets its `JAVA_HOME` variable for it's java executable. It is in the database. It was the value before I made an update to java and deleted the old version and I have changed it from `Bamboo administration > JDKs` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre` and done, the issue is resolved.

Comment: Great ! Spent couple of hours on this checking the env variable and property files and it finally here. Thanks !

Comment: It is not very clear answer man. Changing where? On Bamboo Server? In the terminal? In the GUI? Trying to understand what you did.

Comment: In case anyone gets stuck here - like I did... My issue was caused by mismatching java versions, which flipped the JAVA_HOME variable around. To fix it, I added in a manual 'Environment Variable' on the task configuration section for the bamboo plan, this explicitly set the variable and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be not in the agent configuration, but in the Plan.

Go to Configure Plan -> Stages -> Default Job  and then in the Task itself edit the Environment variables ex. JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.14.0.9-1.el7_9.x86_64"